# how to change xml dynamically in java?

Tags: java, xml

I have written xml file which contains html tags as element like

```
<component>
<input type="button">
<button id="1">
<class="mytest1">
</component>
```

now i want to first write a html file with these tags like

```
<input type="button" class="mytest" id="1">
```

.and when i change button to text,in xml also it shud be change button to text.

Comment: what library are you using for the reading?

Comment: @Eshika : Could you clarify the question a bit more?  Did you 'programmatically'?

Comment: @Adam,I am using DOM Parser to read one by one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Every time your HTML is changed, a method should be called which then processes the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a watch service, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). The service will notify you of any changes and you can take the appropriate action.

Comment: I think that the HTML is already being parsed by his application, so, he wouldn't need a watch service.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya: The watch service will tell him when the XML/HTML files have been changed. It does not do any parsing.

Comment: I know, but, if he's already got a variable *containing* the HTML, you wouldn't want to watch the file, you might as well watch that variable.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya: What you are saying does make sense to a certain point. That being said, the OP mentioned files, not variables.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.But my problem is that i have written xml file which contains html tags as element like<component><input type="button"><button id="1"><class="mytest1">,now i want to first write a html file with these tags like <input type="button" class="mytest" id="1">.I hope u understood my point.and when i change button to text,in xml also it shud be change button to text.

Comment: @Eshika: The answer I proposed should allow you to receive notifications when you save your changes to a file. Once that changes are saved, you will receive a notification. I was assuming that you already had the XML to HTML and vice versa mechanism in place.